# Converting to a specific type from a string value by passing the required type as parameter

Tags: c#-4.0, generics, types, type-conversion

I am using the following method to convert string type to a generic type

```
public static T Parse<T>(string value)
{
    // or ConvertFromInvariantString if you are doing serialization
    return (T)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T)).ConvertFromString(value);
}
```

I have to call it like this

```
Parse<Int32>(Some string value);
Parse<DateTime>(Some string value);
```

I am trying **`that instead of giving the result type explicitly`**, i can give it like

```
Parse<Type.GetType("Int32")>(Some string value);
```

Answer (score 5):

Generics are off the table here.  Primary issue is that you are trying to take a shortcut around *type identity*.  The name of a type is *not* just the type name that you use in a program.  It also includes the namespace it is declared in, the display name of the assembly in which it is stored, the version number of the assembly and the public key token for the assembly's strong name.  In other words, the Type.AssemblyQualifiedName.

Which requires you to write your code similar to this:

```
 Parse(Type.GetType("System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089""), SomeStringValue);
```

That will work just fine.  But I'd guess that you are not going to enjoy writing that.  Otherwise gives you insight in what a compiler does when it reads "Int32" in your program.  It will look in its symbol table that was primed with the reference assemblies you added and notes what possible matches there may be in that table, considering what *using* directives are in effect.

You'd have to implement something similar in your program.  The equivalent of the compiler's symbol table is a `Dictionary<string, Type>`.  You can prime it by populating it with the kind of types that you prefer to use with a short string name.  Like

```
  LookupTable.Add("Int32", typeof(int));
  LookupTable.Add("String", typeof(string));
  // etc...
```

Now you can write:

```
  Parse(LookupTable["Int32"], SomeStringValue);
```

That will work just fine.  But I'd guess that you are not going to enjoy writing that.  Pretty hard to beat the compiler.

Comment: Just a little from MSDN about [Type.GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/w3f99sx1): <<If the type is in the currently executing assembly or in Mscorlib.dll, it is sufficient to supply the type name qualified by its namespace.>> So basically if you only need to convert from system types Type.GetType("System.Int32") is enough.

Comment: @Hans sir I tried with the Dictionary approach, the problem is still the same.

Answer (score 2):

I think that if you need to specify the type at runtime instead of compile time (as in your example where you have specified "Int32" as a string) then first you need to rewrite your code with something like:

```
public static object Parse(Type destinationType, string value)
{
    return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(destinationType).ConvertFromString(value);
}
```

Now you can call this new method writing:

```
var myValue = Parse(Type.GetType("System.Int32"), "33243");
```

`Type.GetType` requires you to specify the full namespace and the assembly name (Assembly qualified name), but for mscorlib types (like all primitive types) or for the currently executing assembly types you only need to specify the full namespace, like `System.Int32` or `System.DateTime`. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/w3f99sx1).

Consider also that there are other option to convert primitive types to and from string. I suggest you to use `Convert.ChangeType`. This method basically check if the specified type support the `IConvertible` interface. Basically you can write just:

```
var myValue = Convert.ChangeType("23423", typeof(Int32));
or
var myValue = Convert.ChangeType("23423", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
```

It also support InvariantCulture:

```
var myValue = Convert.ChangeType("23423", typeof(Int32), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

There is also a good library that combine `IConvertible` feature and `TypeConverter`, see [Code Project: Universal Type Converter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/248440/Universal-Type-Converter). This library as many useful features and it is free, also available on nuget.